# Can you inspect code from "own" package with importlib.metadata?

Tags: python, package, python-importlib

I have a wheel-packaged web application which gets installed into the active environment.

Inside of that package I want to access the version of itself via `importlib.metadata` so I don't have to rely on some convention like providing a `__version__` object at the packages's root.

Is that possible? Currently I can only read the version of *other* packages installed in this particular environment, following the description in https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html

For example: If this code below is packaged in a wheel with version `0.1.1` then self_version should be `0.1.1`.

```py
from importlib.metadata import version  

# How to determine 'the_name_of_the_package_this_code_runs_in'?
# Is there another way?
self_version = version('the_name_of_the_package_this_code_runs_in')
```

Comment: Use the special [`__package__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__package__#package__) variable.